# "Cluster deformers" in Blender

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

Does Blender have anything like Maya's (and, perhaps, C4D's) *cluster deformer* – the ability to group vertices and assign degrees of influence from the cluster parent to subsets of vertices in the cluster?

You can assign vertices to a vertex group and weight paint them accordingly, but what would be the analogue of the cluster parent here? A non-deforming bone?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like you're looking for the [Hook modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/hooks.html).

Comment: Thanks, Fweeb, very helpful. Was thinking hooks might be the way to go, but didn't remember they were a modifier.